# Training PyTorch model on Google Colab Pro crashes

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a model that finds road lanes. I have `191070 training images` and `191070 validation images`. I'm trying my model on this dataset using PyTorch. But when I start the training process `(5 epochs, batch_size=256, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)`, it always crashes something like an hour later. Here is the recent error that I got:

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/content/drive/MyDrive/path_to_dataset/data/train/image-188463.jpg'
```

When I check the image, nothings wrong. I'm using **Google Colab's Pro** version. I have more powerful GPU's than standard Colab version. Why do I get this error while training my model? Is it because the dataset is too big? If so, what should I do to prevent this error? Also I'm getting images from **Google Drive**. I tried to download these files to Colab session but because the images are in a folder, I couldn't download the images.

Comment: Are you able to open that specific image using PIL? (in a separate script)

Comment: When I tried to delete and upload image to Drive again, it said "There is no data in this image".